# Converting from enhanced for loop to for loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I am looking to write a method without using enhanced loops, but am not sure how to convert them exactly. The method is:

```
public static int charFrequency (String[]s, char c){

    int freq = 0;
    for(String s2 : s) {
        char[] newArray = createChars(s2);
        for (char c2: newArray)
            if(c2 == c) freq++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problems you are facing? Also why would you want to reduce readability of your code?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to do this? The newer style of loop is there precisely so that you don't have to use the old-style loop.

Comment: [The for Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: Really I'm just looking for an example of what a for loop would look like if it was derived from an enhanced for loop.

Comment: @templatetypedef for no other reason than learning both.  I taught myself a bit of java and am trying to learn all the different kinds of loops.  I'm trying to figure out how the enhanced loop is created from a regular for loop by working backwards

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
for(int index = 0 ; index < s.length ; index++){
    //Logic
}
```